# Keras: get output before activation

Tags: python, keras

In pretrained VGG19 model layers are defined like

```
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3),
                  activation='relu',
                  padding='same',
                  name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
```

I'm using already pretrained network, is it possible to get output before relu activation? or it's only an option to create new model with separate conv2d and activation and copy weights from pretrained model?

Comment: You can add the activation as a separate layer instead of in the call of Conv2D if that suits your need ?

Comment: @T.Lucas I'm using already pretrained network, is only option to create new model with separate conv2d and activation and copy weights from pretrained model?

Comment: I think so yes (at least i don't know another solution)

Comment: Other solutions might involve replacing the `Conv2D` class with a custom `Conv2D` class where you replace the `call` method (copied from the source code online) and add a line to store the tensor before the line where activation is applied (I say "store" it as a property of the layer, since it will cause lots of bugs if you make it an output - the code for creating the model is not expecting multiple outputs from those layers)

Comment: You may get the tensor then with `model.layers[i].non_activated_output` or something like that (you choose the property name). It might be necessary to add `_keras_shape` and `_keras_history` (equal to those of the main output, probably) if you are going to use that tensor in layers (unless a custom layer accesses that tensor directly from inside its call, recommended).  All this may work without changing a line of code in the model's definition, but will probably cause serialization problems making it hard to save/load the entire model.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may disable the activation by model.layers[*the layer your want to output*].activation = None after loading the pre-trained model. Then compile the model using model.compile(). Then the output of the layer you chose should be before activation.